# image extension validation error

Tags: php, yii

I am giving the validation rule for image file types is:

```
array('employeedetails_photo', 'file', 'types' => 'jpg,gif,png', 'allowEmpty' => true,'on' => 'insert', 'on' => 'update'),
```

But, the problem is that if extension of `.doc` file is changed to `.docx.jpg` and upload this as employee photo is also accepted. How to give validation for this issue in yii ?

Comment: Try this http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-validate-an-image-upload.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to validate pictures is to recreate them using GD `imagecreatefrom*` (or Imagick) and save/replace the processed image. The most simple example

```
public function rules(){
  return array(
    array( 'employeedetails_photo', 'validateImage' )
  );
}

public function validateImage( $attribute ){
  $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($this, $attribute);
  if ( !$file ) {
    return;
  }
  // http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php
  // These types will be automatically detected if your build of PHP supports them: JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP, and GD2
  $gd = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file->getTempName()));
  if ($gd === false) {
    $this->addError($attribute, 'Image is corrupted');
  }
}
```

Comment: this is for an image right. If validate a doc file like this, what will do?

Comment: Use native CFileValidator and check both extensions and MIME-types. `array('employeedetails_photo', 'file', 'mimeTypes' => [], 'types' => [])` @Arya

Answer (score 0):

You must check file type with file mimetype. Php should made it for you.  [use mime-content-type function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)